# MaterialAlertDialog theme is broken on ComponentActivity

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I am currently working on an Android application which is mainly write with the XML framework for the views and in which one I am currently adding a screen based on Jetpack Compose.

In my project, I use custom layout in order to display a custom `MaterialAlertDialog`.

Here the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  style="@style/CustomCardView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
  >

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      style="@style/TextViewRegular.DialogTitle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:text="@string/dialogMessage_newGridCompleted"
      />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn"
      style="@style/DialogButtonOk"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
      android:text="@android:string/ok"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
      />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

And here the styles used in this layout:

```
  <style name="CustomCardView"
    parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardBackground</item>
  </style>
```

```xml
  <style name="TextViewRegular"
    parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/avenir_next_regular</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/avenir_next_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
  </style>

  <style name="TextViewRegular.DialogTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
  </style>
```

```xml
  <style name="DialogButtonOk"
    parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/avenir_next_regular</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/avenir_next_regular</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/btnBackground</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">5.5dp</item>
  </style>
```

And now, the code I use in order to display the alert dialog:

```kotlin
private fun displayDialog(@StringRes messageRes: Int)
{
    val customView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_simple_btn, null, false)

    customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)?.setText(messageRes)

    val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this).apply {
      setView(customView)
      setCancelable(false)
    }.create()


    dialog?.apply {
      window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_dialog)
      show()
    }

    customView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)?.setOnClickListener {
      dialog?.dismiss()
    }
  }
```

and here the drawable bg_dialog.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle"
  >
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
  <corners android:radius="16dp" />
  <padding
    android:left="16dp"
    android:right="16dp"
    />
</shape>
```

When it's used in an `AppCompatActivity`, the result is the one expected:

[image]

But when it's used in a `ComponentActivity`, the style of the button is broken. As you can see, on the button, the background is missing. The ripple effect is also missing.

[image]

Do you know what is the issue?

Comment: In your case use an AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But according to jetpack compose templates, it seems that the use of ComponentActivity is the norm. 

It's not possible to use a MaterialAlertDialog in a ComponentActivity?

Comment: I don't know if this can be fixed, but there is a built-in composable function in jetpack compose called "AlertDialog",  you may want to check it and customize as you like. At least, you can use a fully supported Alert Dialog in ComponentActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to the comment of @Abdulrahman Bahaml, I have discovered the Jetpack Component `Dialog`. I used it in order to recreate my custom dialog for compose screen.

Here the result:

[image]